# Row color and Alternate Row color for Table in Telerik Reporting

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have reporting tool in my program. I want to change row's background color while row's property IsCampaign == true. How do I give row color and alternate row color for a Table in Telerik report? I googled it and I found most of the result says something like "= IsCampaign == true" OK! But where should I place this stuff?

Here is my report page. It is dynamic. Row number getting increased with product count. Table's name is table1.

[image]

And here is my code for report table

```
public OrderFormReport(Order pOrder, List<OrderDetail> pOdList)
{
     InitializeComponent();
     order = pOrder;
     odList = pOdList;

     txtOrderNote.Value = order.Notes;
     txtTotal.Value = order.Total;
     table1.DataSource = odList;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advice.

Comment: Is SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) your reporting tool?

Comment: No, I am using third part application Telerik Reporting @CuriousKid

Comment: Then i am removing the reporting services tag from the question as it is misleading. reporting services tag represents SSRS platform.

Comment: Okey. Thank you.

Comment: maybe this can help. > http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/faq-alternating-style